# Replacement in a loop using find and sed

Tags: linux, for-loop, sed, find

Please help me with advice

I need to go through the files in this $tmp directory and make substitutions in the lines according to the rule described in sed

I trained on one file and this **sed** worked it out normally.
But when I perform a replacement in *for* , I get some nonsense on the output

```
for file in $tmp/*.txt; do
    find $tmp/ -type f -name "*.txt" -exec sed -i -e 's/, /\n''/g; s/"//g; s/$/\x0A/; s/:[ ]/;/g;  s/\n''/;\n''/g; s/^[ t]*//' {} \;
done
```

How can I fix it?
Thanks…

**UP**

I did it.

find - It was really unnecessary

[@Rob Sweet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11626637/rob-sweet) Thanks!

Comment: Unless I'm missing something you don't need the for loop.   You're essentially looping twice, because the find command literally means "do this for every file in $tmp that matches "*.txt".   So either just use the sed command in the loop, or get rid of the for loop.

Comment: @RobSweet - make this an answer! Get the points! :-)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the for loop AND the find command.  Both essentially do the same thing, which is to iterate through all the files in /tmp that match *.txt.

Answer (score 0):

When you don't need to edit files in a subdir of `/tmp`, than give `sed` all files in once.

```
sed -i your_command *.txt
```

Off topic:
I don't understand your `sed` command. Why two single quotes? When you want to replace a newline, consider option `-z`.